# How to configure RAID 1 on Intel Rapid Storage, and partitioning design

Tags: partitioning, bios, raid, lvm, intel-rst

**I would like guidance on setting up a RAID 1 system from BIOS with Intel Rapid Storage.**

#### System details:

I have Click BIOS II running on a MSI motherboard (Z77A-G43).
I also have 2 x 2TB hard drives.

#### What I've done so far:

From the BIOS, I have selected "RAID Mode" from *Settings->Advanced->Integrated Peripherals->SATA Configuration->SATA Mode*.

Now, when I reboot, I get an option to enter the "*Intel Rapid Storage Technology*"        ROM.
When I select "*Create a RAID Volume*", I'm given the option to choose the capacity.

#### Questions:

1. Is it possible to choose a lower capacity - eg 1TB - which would leave the rest of each disk outside of the RAID system?
2. Is this advisable?
3. If I already have data on one drive, would it be kept after this operation?

I plan to partition the disks to have a dual boot, for Windows and Linux, possibly with a separate partition for data.  Its this data partition that I really need the RAID for.

1. Can I use LVM on top of RAID?
2. Is LVM for Linux only?

Any advice would be welcome.